# Use specific native query for Oracle / PostgreSql in Spring @Query annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have one method in `spring repository` like `native`

```
@Repository
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, String> {
    @Query(value = "select sm.* from MESSAGES ...", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Message> findReadyToSend();
}
```

This query for Oracle but I have PostgreSQL, too, and I need create native query for PostgreSQL and when I start my spring boot server with Postgres profile, I need use this query. When I start with Oracle profile, I need use query for Oracle.

For example I can move query string to configuration file:

```
in oracle profile config:
query=select sm.* from MESSAGES ... (oracle)

in Postgre profile config:
query=select sm.* from MESSAGES ... (PostgreSQL)
```

But how can I pass this string to `@Query` annotation? Something like this:

```
String query - get from config;

@Query(value = query)
```

Maybe there is a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to provide two good old fashioned implementations of the interface and add the @Profile annotation in order to indicate which bean to be activated according to the active spring profile.

So the interface would be:

```
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, String> {
    List<Message> findReadyToSend();
}
```

And you would have two implementations, one for Oracle and the other for Postgres:

```
   @Profile("Oracle")
   @Repository
    public class MessageRepositoryOracleImpl implements MessageRepository  {

    @Override
    List<Message> findReadyToSend(){
    Query oracleQuery = .....
    return result;
    }
        .....
```

.

```
 @Profile("Postgres")
 @Repository
 public class MessageRepositoryPostgresImpl implements MessageRepository  {

    @Override
    List<Message> findReadyToSend(){
    Query postgresQuery = .....
    return result;
    }
        ....
```

Make sure that the implementations are picked up by the Spring context. From the @Repository annotation I assume you are using a component scan. If not, then you would need to define the beans in a Java config and use the @Profile annotation there.